# How to extract files in a zip directly in the current directory?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I have a zip file in my ubuntu ec2 instance I extract with `unzip my_file.zip`.

However, the extracted files are put together into a directory `my_file`. My purpose is to to extract the files directly in the current directory without creating the `my_file` folder.

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

This [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72838/unzip-file-contents-but-without-creating-archive-folder) from the Unix Stack Exchange is what you want. (This is not a duplicate on Stack Overflow since other unzip questions are about other tools besides `unzip`)

Use `unzip -j` flag if you want all files to be dumped in current directory (ALL folders and subfolders removed).

Use `bdstar --strip-components=1` tool for stripping just the first folder.

Comment: Some zip contain a directory that wraps all files and some don't. So I need a command that automatically knows what to do and ONLY removes the wrapping folder when there is one. If no wrapping directory just doing normal extraction. Which is the best option for me ?

Comment: Seems like writing a bash script for this would do what you want. The script could determine if there is a wrapper folder (perhaps by comparing folder name with zip file name?) and then call the appropriate commands to handle it. I'm unaware of any tools that automatically have the behavior you want without the user specifying a flag to handle certain cases.